# Pass an array by ajax to php page

Tags: php, ajax

I need to pass an array to a php page with AJAX. This array of input elements gets sent to the other page:

```
<input type="text" name="txtCoursesNamewith[]" id="txtCoursesNamewith" size="117" >
```

This is how I prepare it for sending:

```
var txtCoursesNamewith = $.serialize($('#txtCoursesNamewith').val());
```

But I get this error when running the script:

> TypeError: $.serialize is not a function

How can I send an array with AJAX?

Comment: I assume that you want to serialize several fields. Am I right? Or is it only one value you want to send with ajax?

Answer (score 1):

I am facing same problem and, i am just using code like this.
but first of all please insert one hidden field and set textbox id like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="txt_count" id="txt_count" value="3" />
<input type="text" name="txtCoursesNamewith[]" id="txtCoursesNamewith1" size="117" >
<input type="text" name="txtCoursesNamewith[]" id="txtCoursesNamewith2" size="117" >
<input type="text" name="txtCoursesNamewith[]" id="txtCoursesNamewith3" size="117" >

<script type="text/javascript">
var txt_count= $('#txt_count').val();
for (i=1; i<=txt_count; i++){
   queryString += "&txtCoursesNamewith%5B%5D=" + $('#txtCoursesNamewith'+i).val();
}
</script>
```

finally we can pass `queryString` variable to ajax, and you can print array.

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_GET); // or print_r($_POST);    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because $.serialize($('#txtCoursesNamewith').val()) is a string and not a jQuery object, it doesn't have the serialize function.

If you want to serialize the input (with its value), use $('#txtCoursesNamewith').serialize();

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST', 
url: your url,
data: $('#'+form_id).serialize(), 
  success: function(data) {
    $('#debug').html(data);
  }
});
```

Then in php

```
<?php
  print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: its send me like this its not an arrya txtCoursesNamewith%5B%5D=%D9%84%D9%84%D9%84%D9%84

Answer (score 0):

```
var textBoxes;   
$('input[name="txtCoursesNamewith[]"]').each(function() {
textBoxes+=$(this).val()+"|||";
});
```

Now the `textBoxes` have all the values of text field with **|||** separated and pass to php script and use `explode()` function to split each input value . may it helps u

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `.val()` because `.serialize()` works on a the field itself, not on the value. (because it needs to get the name and the value from the field)

You can also call `serialize()` directly on a jQuery object, rather than using the jquery object as a parameter. Do it like this:

```
var txtCoursesNamewith = $('#txtCoursesNamewith').serialize();
```

Hope that helps.